# Stop iframe from redirecting outside the page, instead redirect inside the iframe

Tags: html, redirect, iframe

I have this problem where I'm trying to use a **website** inside of my own (using iframe), and whenever it redirects it will redirect *outside* the of the iframe (to another tab), where, in my case, I would like it to take the redirect url and put it inside of the iframe, stopping the redirect problem.

```
<iframe src="http://aleks.com" sandbox="allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

Comment: Holy Cr$%! I'm Matt Corley as well! You are aptly named, sir. It's an honor to meet you :D

Comment: @zer00ne no way! awesome!

Comment: Yes way! IKR?! I know that other MCs exist but I never met one until now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Give your iframe a `name="any_name"`
2. Make an anchor with `href="url_of_site_in_iframe"`
3. Give the anchor the target attribute with the value of the iframe's name `target="any_name"`.

#### SNIPPET

```css
a {
  margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
div {
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href='https://www.example.com/' target='iName'>Example</a>
</div>

<iframe src='about:blank' name='iName' width='400' height='400'></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The website may not allow embedding their site within an iframe. This is a security measure to prevent clickjacking.

So the website you are trying to embed may be using something like the X-Frame-Options HTTP response header.

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>, <iframe> or <object>` . Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: I see, I believe that's my problem as iframe stays in iframe by default. However is there a way to set the iframe url when the login button is pressed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - you'll have to update your question above with a sample of your code so we can better see what you're working with.